# Is there a better way to implement the selu activation function for the gpu?

Tags: optimization, theano

So I'm trying to implement the selu activation in `theano` from this [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1706.02515.pdf).
My current implementation is:

```
def selu(x):                                                                    
    alpha = 1.6733                                                              
    lambda_ = 1.0507                                                            
    inds = x <= 0                                                               
    selu = (alpha * theano.theano.tensor.exp(x) - alpha)                        
    x = theano.tensor.set_subtensor(x[inds.nonzero()],selu[inds.nonzero()])        
    x = lambda_ * x                                                             
    return x
```

Unfortunately I "cannot" use the popular framework `Keras` so I've gone about trying to implement it myself.
I am not very familiar with techniques needed to make a function gpu friendly and thus I am reaching out for help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It turns a much much faster solution is the following:

```
import theano                                                                   
def selu(x):                                                                    
    alpha = 1.6733                                                              
    lambda_ = 1.0507                                                            
    return lambda_ * theano.tensor.nnet.elu(x, alpha=alpha)
```